# R shiny: how to embed sliderInputs/selectInputs and radioButtons in a data frame ? (Error: cannot coerce class ""shiny.tag"" to a data.frame)

Tags: html, r, shiny

I need to embed different types of Inputs in a matrix. It works fine for textInput() and numericInput(), but I can't find a way for selectInput(), sliderInput() and radioButton().

I can specify the textInput and the numericInput in HTML, using something like

```
paste0("<input id='num", 1:2, "' class='shiny-bound-input' type='text' value=''>")
```

However I did not find the right way to specify the other types of inputs in HTML. For the sliders for example, I've tried

```
paste0("<input id='Sl_", 1:2, "' class='jslider shiny-bound-input' type = 'range' value='20' min='0' max='100'>")
```

but the result is not a shiny-type slider.

So I tried to use the Shiny commands:

```
lapply(1:2, function(i) sliderInput(inputId = paste0("sl", i), label = "", min = 0, max =100, value = 50)).
```

The Error that I get is: cannot coerce class ""shiny.tag"" to a data.frame. So I deduct that I should specify them in HTML -> does somebody know how to do this ?

Here is the code (and you can see the picture here below):

```
ui = pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("TEST"),
  sidebarPanel(
    helpText('Some types of input can be included in a matrix and some do not')
    ),
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput('matrix_text'),
    uiOutput('matrix_num'),
    uiOutput('matrix_slider'),
    uiOutput('matrix_select'),
    uiOutput('matrix_radioButtons')
  )
)

server = function(input,output){

  output$matrix_text <- renderTable({

    matrix_input <- paste0("<input id='num", 1:2, "' class='shiny-bound-input' type='text' value=''>")
    matrix <- data.frame(matrix_input)

    row.names(matrix) <- c("r 1","r 2")
    colnames(matrix) <- c('C 1')
    matrix
  },sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)


 output$matrix_num <- renderTable({

   matrix_input <- paste0("<input id='num", 1:2, "' class='shiny-bound-input' type='number' value=''>")
   matrix <- data.frame(matrix_input)

   row.names(matrix) <- c("r 1","r 2")
   colnames(matrix) <- c('C 1')
   matrix
 },sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)


output$matrix_slider <- renderTable({

  matrix_input <- lapply(1:2, function(i) sliderInput(inputId = paste0("sl", i), label = "", min = 0, max =100, value = 50))  

  matrix <- data.frame(matrix_input)

},sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)

output$matrix_select <- renderTable({

  matrix_input <- lapply(1:2, function(i) selectInput(inputId = paste0("select", i), label = "", choices = c("Cylinders" = "cyl","Transmission" = "am")))  

  matrix <- data.frame(matrix_input)

},sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)

output$matrix_radioButtons <- renderTable({

  matrix_input <- lapply(1:2, function(i) radioButtons(inputId = paste0("radio", i), label = "",choices= c("Cylinders" = "cyl","Transmission" = "am"), selected = NULL))  

  matrix <- data.frame(matrix_input)

},sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)


}    

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Any advice/suggestion would be highly appreciated and thanks in advance
Cheers
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution. For radioButtons for ex, the code would be:

```
paste0("<div class='control-group shiny-input-radiogroup shiny-bound-input' id='radio",1:2,"'>
    <label class='control-label' for=='radio",1:2,"'>Individual</label>
    <label class='radio'>
    <input id=='radio1",1:2,"' name='radio",1:2,"' type='radio' value='cyl'>
    <span>Cylinders</span>
    </label>
    <label class='radio'>
    <input id=='radio2",1:2,"' name='radio",1:2,"' type='radio' value='am'>
    <span>Transmission</span>
    </label>
    </div>")
```

It is obtainable by right-clicking on a webpage with some radioButtons and selecting 'Inspect element'.

Hope this will help others...